# Angular Position of the Man

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

***A man is standing at a distance of 60m from one tree and 54m from another tree on a playground. If the area of the triangle formed by the man and two trees is 810m², at what angular position is the man standing with these two trees?***

I have been struggling with this question. I am try to solve this question making different scenarios but I am not able to figure out the answer so I am posting it for your help.

In 1st Scenario, I tried making the both trees in same direction but I am stuck in an stage that I am not able to deal with.

In Scenario 2, I supposed that the trees are at different direction but even this seems a bit more realistic, no more contribution it added in my problem solving. I am stuck in finding the sides and the other angles."

That's why I strongly request this math community to solve my question. Before you try this, I want to let you know that this is a **District Mathematics Olympiad (DMO)** question. It has also provided some options which are as follows:

***i.45°       ii.60°      iii.15°        iv.30°***

Comment: All caps is the internet equivalent of yelling. You are yelling in your ttle line.

Comment: Just set it up.  Area = $\frac 12bh=810$.  $b$ can be either of the two lengths.  Then $h$ is $\sin Angle \times hypotenuse$ and $hypotenuse$ is the other length.  So $\frac 12\cdot 60\cdot 54\cdot \sin Angle = 810$.

Comment: Can someone post it with a figure?

Comment: "Can someone post it with a figure? "  just draw it yourself.  Draw a triangle.  Then use a dotted line to drop a perpendicular down from  one of the trees.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that the area of a triangle is $\frac12 ab\sin(C)$, where $a$ and $b$ are two sides of the triangle and $C$ is the angle between them. We know that this expression is $810$ meters squared, and we can let $a=60$ and $b=54$. So we have $$810=30\times54\sin(C)\implies\frac{810}{30\times54}=\sin(C)\implies\frac12=\sin(C)$$I will let you take it on from here.

Edit: I made it clearer why the area is $\frac12ab\sin(C)$ [here](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1hRmdIbxw1mO8pypAs5pqMpDcsOm2LbwYM7JHIhrRhVY/edit)

Comment: "It is known that the area of a triangle is 12absin(C)" For a student at the OP level it might be a good idea to explain why this is so.

Comment: Can you post it making an appropriate figure of it?

Comment: @fleablood good suggestion, but I think OP understands this.

Comment: I am not able to understand this without the figure.

Comment: @TechnoHighway Yes I will add a picture.

Comment: @TechnoHighway I added the picture. Please reply to me if you have any confusion.

Comment: I suggest the OP draw their own figure.  Draw a triangle between the man and the two trees.  Then as a dotted line drop a perpendicular from either tree to the side of a triangle.

Comment: why to drop a perpendicular?

Comment: @TechnoHighway By dropping a perpendicular, you make an altitude for the triangle, and using the definition of sine you can get an expression for the height depending on C. Just look at my drawing and you will see what I mean.

Comment: My question is why is altitude needed here?

Comment: @TechnoHighway We know the area of the triangle and its base, but the height depends on $\sin (C)$. So this way, we could solve for $\sin(C)$ and then you get the answer.

Comment: But we can directly find it by using Area= 1/2*a*b(sinc) solving it we get c=30 degree
so, what is the necessity of height?

Comment: @TechnoHighway That’s why I thought you understood what I was doing, the drawing proves that formula assuming you don’t know it. But apparently you do.

Comment: Can you please solve this question too?
A dog of height 2 ft. stands on a table. The angle subtended by the dog and the table at a bone placed on the floor of are 30° and 30° respectively. Find the height of table.

Comment: Ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your suggestion.I have asked this as a separate question. please answer it.